# parse variable length comma separated list into command

Tags: math-mode, macros, latex3, comma-separated-list

I've been trying to modify the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74396/smart-vector-command) into a LaTeX3 command that takes a variable length comma separated list of numbers and an optional argument (a unit) and prints the square root of the sum of the square of each number (along with the unit, if given).

`\sumofsquares{2,3,-4}[m/s]` should give

[image]

but `\sumofsquares{3,-4}[m/s]` should give

[image]

I've Googled for LaTeX3 examples but the ones I've found (documentation for `xparse` and `expl3`) don't contain any examples. The differences between lists and sequences mystifies me.

Comment: A `sequence` is just a linear array of items.  It has a first item, a second item and so on.  To make one, you just take a list of things whose distinct elements are separated by some specific character, say `;` and use `\seq_set_split:Nnn {name}{separator}{list}`.  `expl3` then provides functions for working with them.  Think of a `clist` as a `sequence` whose separator is a comma.  Functionally, I don't think there's much difference between them.  `sequence`'s are more versatile, `clist`'s maybe shorten some syntax.

Comment: A comma list is 'closer' to user syntax than a sequence: more convenient in many cases but not quite as general. As is mentioned in one of the answers, your input syntax is odd: I'd expect either `\sumofsquares[m/s]{2,3,4}` or `\sumofsquares{2,3,4}{m/s}` (with no optional argument).

Comment: @Joesph The package I'm developing defines syntax the way one would say it. One always says units after the numerical value of a physical quantity. I can't see how or why it should be any other way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an option using sequences, it could probably be made a little more compact as the code from the two helper macros is almost identical.

I'm not an expert so take my advice with a grain of salt but I would just stick with using `sequences`.  They require an extra line of code here and there, but the additional options that they provide are well worth it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\sumofsquares}{ m o }
    {
        \IfNoValueTF {#2}
            % if optional is missing call this
            {\sum_of_squares:n {#1}}
            % if not, then call this
            {\sum_of_squares:nn {#1}{#2}}
    }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \sum_of_squares:n #1
    {
        % does what the name suggests, set a sequence from the clist
        \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1}
        % applies final arg to each element of second seq and stores result in first seq
        \seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq {(##1)^2}
        % \seq_use puts the items from the seq back in the input with "+" as a separator
        \sqrt{\seq_use:Nnnn \l_tmpb_seq {+}{+}{+}}
    }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \sum_of_squares:nn #1 #2
    {
        % same as above, but with the addition of units
        \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1}
        \seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq {(\SI{##1}{#2})^2}
        \sqrt{\seq_use:Nnnn \l_tmpb_seq {+}{+}{+}}
    }


\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

$\sumofsquares{2,3,-4}$\par\medskip
$\sumofsquares{2,3,-4}[m/s]$

\end{document}
```

Here's a slightly shorter (and less clear) example using `clist`s.  The same method could have been used to shorten the code above.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\sumofsquares}{ m O{} }
    {
        \sum_of_squares:nn {#1}{#2}
    }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \sum_of_squares:nn #1 #2
    {
        \tl_if_empty:nTF {#2}
            {
                \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {#1}
                \sqrt{(\clist_use:Nnnn \l_tmpa_clist {)^2+(} {)^2+(} {)^2+(} )^2 }
            }
            {
                \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {#1}
                \sqrt{(\clist_use:Nnnn \l_tmpa_clist {\,\si{#2})^2+(} {\,\si{#2})^2+(} {\,\si{#2})^2+(} \,\si{#2})^2}
            }
    }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

$\sumofsquares{2,3,-4}$\par\medskip
$\sumofsquares{2,3,-4}[m/s]$

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think I'm taking LaTeX "programming" too literally. I have to remember that it's still a macro expansion markup. BTW, does the shorter solution allow for an arbitrary number of numerical arguments like the first solution?

Comment: Hi Joe: the second version also allows for an arbitrary number of arguments. They work the same, but because `clists` don't offer the equivalent of `set_map`, I used a workaround that happened to be a bit shorter.

Comment: Why couldn't/shouldn't `\sum_of_squares:nn` be put within the braces of the `\NewDocumentCommand` code? Why is it needed as an intermediary in the first place? Programmatically, it looks like it shouldn't work as written. Obviously it does, but it still looks nonintuitive to me.

Comment: One more thing. Both version worked perfectly except when I used the first one with `SIunits` instead of `siunitx`. I kept getting "TeX capacity exceeded" errors when using any command defined in `SIunits`. I could define them myself locally and then they sometimes worked. The second example doesn't have this problem.

Comment: Re first comment:  the code of `\sum_of_squares:nn` _could_ be put in the body of `\NewDocumentCommand`.  I have come to understand that doing so is stylistically undesirable.  It has been pointed out that `\NewDocumentCommand` should be used only as a wrapper that passes off control to the relevant `expl3` macros.  In this case `\sumofsquares` simply grabs the two arguments at the document level, and passes them to `\sum_of_squares:nn`.  In the first version, I did that "properly" with the branching in the document command, and in the second I didn't.

Comment: See [these](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73315/14100) [two](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71459/14100) answers from members of the LaTeX3 team for further clarification.

Comment: Re second comment: `\seq_set_map:NNn` requires an expandable third argument.  Presumably, that is the issue with using `SIunits` rather than `siunitx` (see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21936/14100) for a comparison).  The `SIunits` macros are defined with `DeclareRobustCommand` while the `siunitx` macros have `protected` definitions...the difference between the two is something that I'm not clear on.

Comment: I don't like the `siunitx` interface at all. It's far too cumbersome. I'd rather absorb `SIunits` into my own package if it comes down to that.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you can do this just with `xparse`, so

```
$\sumofsquares{2,3,-4}[m/s]$
$\sumofsquares{2,3,-4,4,7}$
```

yields:

[image]

### References:

- This uses the solution from [Use a loop to generate a list for another (foreach) loop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39432/use-a-loop-to-generate-a-list-for-another-foreach-loop) to build up the sequence.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\SequenceOfSquares}{}
\newcommand*{\TermSeparator}{}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\sumofsquares}{m O{}}{%
    \gdef\TermSeparator{}% clear up from last use (if any)
    \def\Sequence{#1}
    \foreach \x in  \Sequence {%
        \xdef\SequenceOfSquares{\SequenceOfSquares \TermSeparator (\SI{\x}{#2})^2}%
        \gdef\TermSeparator{+}%
    }
    \sqrt{\SequenceOfSquares}%
    \gdef\SequenceOfSquares{}%
}

\begin{document}
$\sumofsquares{2,3,-4}[m/s]$

\medskip
$\sumofsquares{2,3,-4,4,7}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is another solution. No need for *xparse* in this solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\sumofsquares[2][]{%
  \def\tempa{}%
  \@for\reserved:=#2\do{%
    \edef\tempa{\tempa\ifx\tempa\empty\else+\fi(\SI{\reserved}{#1})^2}%
  }
  \sqrt{\tempa}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$\sumofsquares[m/s]{2,3,-4}$
\par\medskip
$\sumofsquares{2,3,-4,4,7}$
\end{document}
```

## Putting the optional argument at the end

That is the OP's choice; I don't recommend it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\sumofsquares[1]{\@testopt{\@sumofsquares{#1}}{}}
\def\@sumofsquares#1[#2]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\tempa{}%
  \@for\reserved:=#1\do{%
    \edef\tempa{\tempa\ifx\tempa\empty\else+\fi(\SI{\reserved}{#2})^2}%
  }
  \expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\sqrt\expandafter{\tempa}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$\sumofsquares{2,3,-4}[m/s]$
\par\medskip
$\sumofsquares{2,3,-4,4,7}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, but the OP had requested that the optional parameter be the second parameter, not the first. Not saying that I think that that is a good idea.

Comment: That is easy to address. See the updated solution.

Comment: As I said in a previous comment, one always says/writes the unit after the numerical value, never the other way around. My target audience is students and instructors of physics and I want to encourage a "write what you think" model. It's far more intuitive.