# Command with variable number of arguments to format menu sequences

Tags: macros

I would like to define a command that accepts a variable number of arguments:

```
\menu{foo}
% would result in \emph{foo}

\menu{foo}{bar}
% would result in \emph{foo} $\to$ \emph{bar}

\menu{foo}{bar}{baz}
% would result in \emph{foo} $\to$ \emph{bar} $\to$ \emph{baz}
```

and so on. Is this possible, and if it is, how can I do this?

Comment: Doing it in complete generality is impossible; you need a terminator. A better syntax would be to provide *one* argument as a comma separated list of values.

Comment: Note that in LaTeX you really shouldn't do this as it breaks the syntax rules that latex tries to make consistent. All LaTeX commands always have a fixed number of `{}` argumnets, optional arguments should be `[]` or here probably better a comma separated list within a single argument.

Comment: @egreg and DavidCarlisle, I can see we all had the same idea. I wrote my answer before reading your comments

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate: the linked question is about a completely different need.

Comment: @Tobi You can vote for reopening

Comment: @egreg  "Doing it in complete generality is impossible".  What about my answer here then?  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305383/how-to-write-macro-with-variable-amount-of-text-variables

Comment: @User You're not defining a macro with a variable number of arguments, but a macro with a possibly large, but fixed, number of arguments.

Comment: @egreg. In what sense "fixed"?  I don't think so.  What do you mean than with a "variable number of argument macro"?

Comment: @User In the question, the OP wants a macro that continues to absorb arguments, with no predetermined limit.

Comment: @egreg. My macro does exactly this.  Where have you found the predetermined limit in it?

Comment: @User `\ifnum\NUMARGS=4\endgraf`: this I call a predetermined limit.

Comment: @egreg. Of course, because we already know that the number of arguments of`\sigblock` can vary only between three and four.   But what about the first example called `\mymacro`?  Does the same hold there?  I see no predetermined limit in it

Comment: @User You're using a terminator; precisely, you end when a `{` is not scanned after having absorbed the last braced group as argument. This doesn't make for “full generality”. And it also gobbles spaces at the end of the job.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38684/discussion-between-user-and-egreg).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`menukeys`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/menukeys) … I guess it’s what your looking for ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{menukeys}

% create a new simple style to add arrwos between the items
\newmenustylesimple*{arrows}{\CurrentMenuElement}[ $\to$ ]{blacknwhite}

\begin{document}
\menu{foo > bar > baz}

\bigskip

% apply the new style to the old macro. The optional arguments
% defines the separator, the default is a comma
\renewmenumacro{\menu}[>]{arrows}
\menu{foo > bar > baz}
\end{document}
```

[image: menukeys]

The first line shows the default style of `\menu`, but it’s possible to change it in many ways. The example shows a very simple style. More predefined styles can be found in the manual …

Comment: +1 for letting me know about menukeys. Oh! And for authoring it :-)

Comment: @JLDiaz: Your welcome :-)

Comment: @Tobi I hope you will find a bit of time for working on. :-)

Comment: @Speravir: Me too :-)

Answer (score 13):

Not exactly what you requested, but with the same functionality could be the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}   % you don't need this if tikz is already included
\begin{document}
\def\menu#1{%
 \gdef\firstelement{1}
 \foreach \e in {#1}{%
   \ifnum\firstelement=0$\to$\fi\emph{\e}%
   \gdef\firstelement{0}%
 }
}

\menu{foo}\par
\menu{foo,bar}\par
\menu{foo,bar,baz}\par
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 9):

With LaTeX3 macros, using a list of items instead of a variable number of arguments (which is not recommended in LaTeX) is rather easy.

Why not using a variable number of arguments? The main reason has been explained by David in a comment; another reason is in awkwardness of the implementation; one should start a recursion, store the last found argument and check for a left brace; if found continue the recursion, otherwise stop and output the result. Since the arguments need to be stored anyway, it's better to use one argument and implement the command by cycling over the entries.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\menu}{m}
 {
  \vwegert_menu:nnn { , } { #1 } { \emph }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\xmenu}{O{,}mO{\emph}}
 {
  \vwegert_menu:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \vwegert_menu:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  % split the list at the chosen separator
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_vwegert_input_seq { #1 } { #2 }
  \seq_clear:N \l_vwegert_output_seq
  % add `\emph` around the items (or what's desired)
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_vwegert_input_seq
   { \seq_put_right:Nn \l_vwegert_output_seq { #3{ ##1 } } }
  % print the result
  \seq_use:Nnnn \l_vwegert_output_seq { $\to$ } { $\to$ } { $\to$ }
 }
\seq_new:N \l_vwegert_input_seq
\seq_new:N \l_vwegert_output_seq

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\menu{foo}

\menu{foo,bar}

\xmenu[;]{foo;bar;baz}[\textbf]

\end{document}
```

We have a simple command `\menu` without options and a more powerful one `\xmenu` with which you can change the separator (leading optional argument) or the formatting (trailing optional argument); the trailing optional argument should be a command taking exactly one argument.

The working is:

1. Split the list into components; leading and trailing spaces will be removed.
2. Add to each element the chosen formatting (default `\emph`).
3. Produce each element of the list, with `$\to$` between any two elements.

[image]

Comment: Looking at this answer, the question could be a duplicate of [parse variable length comma separated list into command](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82253), or am I mistaken again? `:-)`

Comment: @HendrikVogt The methods are indeed, similar; but the solution comes only after judging unfeasible the "variable number of arguments" path.