# How to put the triangle arrow

Tags: symbols, lyx

I am looking for this symbol:

> **▷**

I have seen it in the *tutorials and manuals* in menu **Help**. I think it's the code:

```
\lyxarrow{}
```

But in the example it isn't code; I can see:

> • Open a new file with **File ▷ New**

**Edit:** *I know i can put the triangle writing `$\triangleright$` but I'm looking for how to write using the menu. I want to see the triangle in the text directly, without input ERT.*

Comment: You should use the techniques described in [How to look up a symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/5764)

Comment: [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) yields `\triangleright` in math mode (so surround it by `$`...`$`).

Comment: Also see [Create a command for 'menu sequences'](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40613/5764) and [Command with variable number of arguments to format menu sequences](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/101312/5764).

Comment: *I know i can put the triangle writing* `$\triangleright$` *but I'm looking for how to write using the menu. **I want to see the triangle in the text directly**, without input ERT*. Thnx!

Comment: @norbux Okay. I'm updating my answer... (I did not get informed about your last comment, just found it while checking back. In the case, you want to notify me directly, please use `@e-birk` in your comment, or  comment on my answer.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using "View > View Source" you already correctly discovered that LyX uses `\lyxarrow`. But what is the definition of that?

Looking at the beginning of the LaTeX code preview (choose "Complete Source" or "Preamble Only" under "View Source") you will find

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\lyxarrow}{%
\@ifstar
{\leavevmode\,$\triangleleft$\,\allowbreak}
{\leavevmode\,$\triangleright$\,\allowbreak}}
```

Hence, it is `\triangleright` in this case.

**Update:** In LyX, you can insert this symbol using "Insert > Special Character > Menu Separator".