# Why is it impossible to format items of a LaTeX3 comma list?

Tags: formatting, expl3, comma-separated-list

Trying to adapt the 1st code of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82258/18401) in order to format (say in bold) items of a LaTeX3 comma list, I stumbled upon an unexpected error: the following MWE works like a charm:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\bolditems}{ m }
{
  \bold_items:n {#1}
}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \bold_items:n #1
{
  % does what the name suggests, set a sequence from the clist
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1}
  % applies final arg to each element of second seq and stores result in first seq
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq {
    ##1
    % \textbf{##1}
  }
  % \seq_use puts the items from the seq back in the input with "+" as a separator
  \seq_use:Nnnn \l_tmpb_seq {,~}{,~}{,~}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\bolditems{}

\bolditems{foo}

\bolditems{foo,bar}

\bolditems{foo,bar,baz}
\end{document}
```

but, if `##1` is replaced by `\textbf{##1}`, fails with error:

```
! Argument of \reserved@a has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.26 \bolditems{foo}

?
```

Why?

Comment: You should use `\exp_not:N \textbf { ##1 }`; as explained in the interface manual, `\seq_set_map:NNn` tries full expansion of the items it finds. Better yet, perhaps, `\exp_not:n { \textbf { ##1 } }`

Comment: As the documentation says the inline function is x-expanded. So better use `\noexpand\textbf{##1}` (or better the equivalent to \noexpand ;-))

Comment: @egreg Please forgive my naivety, but why full expanded items would be a problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The items passed through `\seq_set_map:NNn` are subject to full expansion. In the application showed in the linked to answer it's not really relevant, but it is in yours, because `\textbf`, and possibly also the items, doesn't survive full expansion. Just use `\exp_not:n`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\bolditems}{ m }
 {
  \bold_items:n {#1}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \bold_items:n #1
 {
  % does what the name suggests, set a sequence from the clist
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1}
  % applies final arg to each element of second seq and stores result in first seq
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq { \exp_not:n { \textbf { ##1 } } }
  % \seq_use puts the items from the seq back in the input with "+" as a separator
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {,~}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
X\bolditems{}X

X\bolditems{foo}X

X\bolditems{foo,bar}X

X\bolditems{foo,bar,baz}X
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note `\seq_use:Nn` that possibly was not available at the time the answer was written.