# How would I know to use #1 versus ##1 in the function used in \seq_set_map?

Tags: expl3, sequence

On page 148 of The LaTeX3 Interfaces (interface3.pdf) dated 2021-10-12, the documentation for `\seq_set_map:Nn` states that the inline function that I'm using should receive each item in the sequence as `#1`. When I do this as illustrated in the MWE below, I obviously get unintended output. I finally figured out from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/275432/218142) that I should use `##1` instead.

Now I understand why using `#1` gives the results it gives; because `#1` is the argument of the outer function. So my question then is, should I know in advance to use `##1` in the mapping function and if so, how would I know that? I understand how to use `##1` when defining a function within a function and passing the argument to the new function, so is this issue related to that one? It occurred to me that the `#1` mentioned in the docs might refer to the argument specification of the mapping function, but if that were the case then using `(#1)^2` inline for the function should work, and it doesn't.

```
% !TEX program = lualatexmk
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \joe_zzzz:n #1
  {
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { #1 }
    %\seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq { \joe_square:n { #1 } } % doesn't work
    \seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq { \joe_square:n { ##1 } } % works
    \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { + }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \joe_square:n #1
  {
    (#1)^2
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{ \zzzz }{ m }
  {
    \joe_zzzz:n { #1 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\( \zzzz{1,2,3} \)
\end{document}
```

Comment: see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71633/1090

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need `#1` in the map, but you have it in the definition `cs_new:Npn \joe_zzzz:n` within a definition `#1` refers to the argument of `\joe_zzzz:n` so you want  `#`. To get a `#` in a definition you use `##`.

`##` is replaced by `#` just as `#1` is replaced by the first argument of the command being defined.

So your line

```
\seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq { \joe_square:n { ##1 } }
```

adds

```
 \seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq { \joe_square:n { #1 } }
```

to the replacement text of the command being defined.